# How to find damping ratio of a 4th order system?

Tags: damping-factor

For example in this 4th order transfer function how the damping ratio would be calculated?
[image]

---

in fact I` m encountered with this problem: If I didnt realize the concept of problem plz guide me:

problem: calculate gain magnitude (k) if damper ratio of closed loop system is 0.7 (it means zita=0.7):

.

open loop transfer function:

[image]

---

the expansion of open loop system fraction:

[image]

and now how much is zita?
quadratic faraction isn t standard form because there s a 's' in numerator, am I right?

---

how much is k due to the zita has a magnitude of 0.7?
[image]

Comment: How the damping ratio is defined for 4'th order system?

Comment: This transfer function does not exhibit any peak in gain.  take the derivative and see why.

Comment: In this case, it probably means the damping coefficient of the bracketed 2nd order term, since this is under-damped. But strictly  it's undefined for a TF higher than 2nd order.

Answer (score 1):

> The damping ratio is a parameter, usually denoted by ζ (zeta),[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_ratio) that
>   characterizes the frequency response of a **second order** ordinary
>   differential equation.

The quote above is taken from [Wikipedia: Damping ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_ratio). In other words it relates to a 2nd order transfer function and not a 4th order system. Having said that, if it is possible to reduce the denominator to two multiplying equations each of the form: -

\$s^2 +2s\zeta \omega_n + \omega_n^2\$ (where \$\zeta\$ is damping ratio and \$\omega_n\$ is natural resonant frequency)

Then it would have some meaning.

Comment: I didnt find out my response

Comment: @somebody If you haven't yet got it, the concept "damping factor" only applies to quadratics. Suppose you have a quadratic: the names of each constant are: *quadratic coefficient*, *linear coefficient* and *constant coefficient*, in that order. The linear coefficient has a certain meaning. Now, suppose someone gave you a 4th order equation. The *linear coefficient* would NOT have the same meaning, anymore. The whole idea is in the trash, so to speak. There is no *understood* and well-defined meaning for "damping ratio" on a 4th order system. So you need to define your meaning.

Comment: @somebody The ***idea*** of a damping factor in 2nd order is as an index of its tendency towards oscillation. If you can work out an index that achieves this goal for 4th order systems, then I think you'd already have your answer anyway. But feel free to discuss it, as a comprehensive study of the set of all possible 4th order filters in this context would actually be interesting to read (to me, anyway.)

Comment: @jonk I would find it interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it probably means the \$\small \zeta\$ of the bracketed 2nd order term, since this is under-damped. But strictly  it's undefined for a TF higher than 2nd order.

Also, this appears to be an open loop TF, so the question may be looking for the 'equivalent' 2nd order closed loop TF where the \$\small \zeta\$ value is given by the ROT: \$\small\zeta\approx 0.01\times PM\$, and \$\small PM\$ is the phase margin in degrees.

Comment: how is the manner of calculating its phase margine?

Comment: From the open loop Bode plot, it's (180 - phase angle) at the frequency where the gain is 0dB