# finding zeta and wn for a 4th order system?

Tags: control, control-system

If we have a 4th order system,such as the one in snapshot,

[image]

how we can find its undamped natural frequency and damping ratio?
Because  on wikipedia ,i found case of 2nd order system and couldn't find case/scenario of fourth order system

apparently another question on EE SE has same subject

[How to find damping ratio of a 4th order system?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350571/how-to-find-damping-ratio-of-a-4th-order-system)

But the issue with this question is that it has no answer that is direct/simple and to the point as can be seen from the wording of those two answers ,they are containing a bit level of uncertainty, and the fact that **OP hasn't accepted anyone of those two answers yet?**

Comment: You can find the 2nd order ‘equivalent’ from the phase margin and gain cross-over frequency.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find damping ratio of a 4th order system?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350571/how-to-find-damping-ratio-of-a-4th-order-system)

Comment: The op hasn’t accepted an answer because he hasn’t been back to this site since the day after he raised the question. Zeta is a 2nd order thing so break your equation into two 2nd order equations that are multiplied together and solve for zeta on both but separately.

Comment: Not shown in Chu's answer, but my natural inclination would be to use [depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Converting_to_a_depressed_quartic) and reduction of the 4th order equation. First, using a linear change of variable, to create different 4th order equation lacking the odd powers, and second using a change of variable to reduce that to a 2nd order. Once that's achieved, you can put it into standard form where \$\zeta\$ is present and may have some meaning. Do you see how that may work for you?

Comment: @jonk better to write your idea here an answer with example?

Comment: @andy aka  we will get two by using your technique.  How can we get the actual required zeta for 4th order?by multiplying or adding the two zetas we get by using your technique?

Comment: There is no such thing as zeta for a fourth order filter or system. Zeta is a 2nd order thing period @Man

Comment: @Man It would be better. I don't have time right now, which is why I took a moment to link something and express enough to know the direction. Second, the OP hasn't replied to me. I wouldn't attempt an answer, at all, without some discussion with the OP.

Comment: @jonk it will be much helpful and easy to understand if express your opinion in form of answer along with an example

Comment: @Andyaka it will be much helpful and good if you express your idea with an example

Comment: @Andyaka  you are saying                                          
   "break your equation into two 2nd order equations that are multiplied together and solve for zeta on both but separately" .                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                             We will get two values of zeta  by using your technique. Will we mutliply those two zeta values or add them to get our actual/required zeta for our 4th order system?

Comment: There is no such thing as "zeta for a 4th order system". Zeta is a 2nd order thing.

Comment: @Man are you in fact @ engr

Comment: @Andyaka Once one understands *any* of this, your statement is so obviously correct. And now that you suggest it, I am wondering if (a) engr is Man; or, b) engr is just copying Man, like a bot. Either way, I don't have the time or inclination to add an answer until engr engages me in a discussion about the approach I suggested. (Which is something I've never tried, but as I imagine it I believe may work "acceptably." If not acceptably, then certainly "interestingly." When I get some time, I'm definitely going to play with the idea and see how it compares to a non-trivial 4th order evaluation.)

Answer (score 1):

Two possible methods of several:

1. A 2nd order CLTF model of a higher order system (viz. the \$\small\zeta\$ and \$ \omega _n\$ values), can be derived from the open-loop gain cross-over frequency, and phase margin, thus:

$$\small\left(\frac{\omega _c}{\omega _n}\right)^2 \approx \sqrt{(4\zeta ^4 +1)}\:-2\zeta^2 $$

and

$$\small\zeta \approx 0.01\times PM $$

where \$\small PM\$ is the phase margin in degrees, and \$\small \omega _c\$ is the frequency at which the open loop gain crosses \$\small 0\:dB\$ (i.e. the frequency at which the phase margin is defined).

This assumes that \$ \omega _c\$ (and consequently the phase margin) exists.

2. Dominant poles: the dominant poles are located at \$\small s=0\$ and \$\small s=-5\$, since the other two poles are at least three times further from the origin than the \$\small (s+5)\$ pole. Hence ignoring the less dominant poles gives the OLTF:

$$\small G_c (s)=\frac{K(s+7)}{s(s+5)} $$

with CLTF:

$$\small G(s)=\frac{K(s+7)}{s(s+5)+K(s+7)}=\frac{K(s+7)}{s^2 +(K+5)s+7K} $$

Comment: What do you mean? Which are less dominant poles?those at -15 and -12?

Comment: Yes, further from origin = less dominant. Check by finding the residues at the poles for a simple 2nd order unit step response like: \$\frac{10}{s(s+1)(s+10)}\$ compared with: \$\frac{1}{s(s+1)}\$.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to write this expression in a *low-entropy* form in which you can see where the poles and zeroes are located. With proper factorization, your expression can be rewritten in the following way: \$G(s)=G_0\frac{1+\frac{\omega_z}{s}}{(1+\frac{s}{\omega_{p1}})(1+\frac{s}{\omega_{p2}})(1+\frac{s}{\omega_{p3}})}\$ with \$G_0=\frac{k}{1500}\$, \$\omega_z=7\;rad/s\$, \$\omega_{p1}=5\;rad/s\$, \$\omega_{p2}=15\;rad/s\$ and \$\omega_{p1}=20\;rad/s\$.

You can then see that you have a pole at the origin, a zero and three poles among which one dominates at low frequency while two are located higher up, close to each other. I would therefore combine the two last ones into a 2nd-order polynomial leading to the following expression:

\$G(s)=G_0\frac{1+\frac{\omega_z}{s}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_{p1}}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_0Q}+(\frac{s}{\omega_0})^2}\$ in which \$Q\$ and \$\omega_0\$ are determined by developing the two higher-frequency cascaded poles. The below Mathcad sheet shows how these transfer functions are equivalent:

[image]

But is this what you were looking for?