# Find a point on root locus for specific damping ratio

Tags: control, stability, root-locus

Although I have seen many types of root locus plots which have some curved behavior, I cannot find the poles for which my system has a given damping ratio of \$ \zeta = 0.59 \$.

I need to somehow find the intersection point between the root locus path and the damping ration line by hand, without using MATLAB for the following 3rd order system:
$$ G(s)= \frac{K}{s(s+3)(s+7)}$$

[image: root locus plots of a third order system]

Comment: **MASSIVE HINT:** Utilize the general characteristic equation of \$s^2+2\zeta s \omega + \omega^2\$ ...... Then you need to use your factoring skills you learned from Algebra. This will help you find your poles.

Comment: The system is 3rd order system G(s)= (K/s(s+3)(s+7)). If It was second order systems it will be easier since the root locus will break away and leave stright

Comment: This is information that is not explained your original post and therefore, I believe [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350571/how-to-find-damping-ratio-of-a-4th-order-system) might provide some details you may need. However, you may find that you still need to provide a characteristic equation to find what you're looking for.

Comment: remember that those poles lie in the line \$ s_0 = - \omega_n (\zeta  + i \sqrt{1 - \zeta^2 } )\$, you have the \$ \zeta \$ and must find the \$ \omega_n \$. But you will probably have to write the closed-loop equation of the system \$ H(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1 + G(s)} \$.

Comment: It's obvious it's 3rd order system each pole represent a one degree and we can see 3 poles in the graph

Comment: @jDAQ this works for 2nd order system not for this system

Comment: well, then explain what you want. Since a damping ratio only makes sense for a **second order** system.

Comment: Also, is this homework? Have you had any similar exercises? How did you solve them? Did any of them have a damping ration even being of order higher than 2? This seems really hard for a pen-and-paper problem.

Comment: The damping ratio of a 2nd order system IS the damping ratio irrespective of frequency applied. A third order system shakes things up a bit but, the damping ratio remains what it was.

Answer (score 2):

The third pole at S = -7 recedes away from the origin along the negative real axis, its effect on the overall transient response becomes less significant. It may generally be ignored if its magnitude is at least 10 times greater than the real part of the complex conjugate roots (which it is).

Therefore you can treat the 'curvey' part of the locus as though your system was second order.

To determine the values of the pair of complex conjugate roots you can use a graphical method.

Damping ratio, zeta = 0.59. Draw a line on your root locus plot from the s-plane's origin to the locus at an angle of cos^-1(0.59) to the real axis. Now you can read off the axes the real and imaginary values of the poles level with where the line from the origin crosses the locus.

You now have the complex conjugate pole values and only need to determine the value of the third pole. You do this by solving the characteristic equation with various values of k inserted.

Characteristic equation = S(S+3)(S+7) + K = 0

Enter various values of K into this equation and solve for S until you converge on the pole values for the complex conjugate pole values which you obtained earlier graphically. You now also have obtained the third pole value and as a bonus you have the value of K which gives these three pole values at a damping ratio of 0.59.

The difficult part is repeatedly solving the cubic equation and I am unable to help you with that.

EDIT

[image: Forward transfer function]

Firstly, you need G(s)H(s), the loop transfer function. I’ve assumed that you have unity feedback and so H(s) = 1.

Secondly, your K (capital K) is not actually the gain because your transfer function is in standard form.

[image: Equation for K]

Where k (lower case k) is the dc open loop gain.

Putting your transfer function in the form necessary to isolate k.

[image: Loop transfer function]

The denominator of the closed loop transfer function (the characteristic equation) now becomes:-

[image: Characteristic equation]

This means that K = 21k
Where k is the dc open loop gain which is to be varied.